# Can the em wave pass through matter obstacles and how?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, wavelength

I know about Faraday's cage, and another screens, but I do not understand the physics of this processes. Well, I know that the atoms are almost empty, so there are a lot of free space to em waves to travel, but how does it related with wavelength of em wave, **considering** the fact that, in classic physics em wave is oscillation of E\B fields strength values, another saying - intensity. I also read that em waves can pass through any non-conductive materials. Why? Non free electrons do not absorb em waves? If yes then ok. But how about conuctors?

Please, explain me the stuff behind this question

Comment: There is indeed a lot of stuff behind your question.  I suggest you look up “Interaction of Radiation With Matter” on the Hyperphysics web site. It provides (in my opinion) an excellent description of how em waves interact with matter based on the wavelength/frequency of the em wave (or photon). By the way, you’ll see that electrons can absorb em radiation. Good luck.

Comment: @BobD, by the way, considering the fact that photons are not a fermions, and hence can occupy one point of the space, if there are two photons with different energy, which of them electron will "absorb"(I notice that energy can be "absorbed" only by quants). And do You mean by "absorb"? Can two or more electrons "absorb" a single photon?

Comment: Good questions. Particle physics is not in my area, but according to the referenced website, "UV photons below the ionization energy are strongly absorbed in producing electron transitions". I suppose that if there are two photons with different energy,  the electrons will absorb one or both if the photon energy level corresponds to the transition level(s). Truthfully, however, I can't say for certain.